# Error: Can't connect to mysql server on 'ip' 10061

Tags: 16.04, mysql

How can I check what problem is by steps?
I want to check default port of mysql.
Also I want to check something else more.
What's the steps for solving this problem?

---

**Problem Situation**

- The mysqld is running on my Ubuntu 16.04LTS. This is my remote server.
- A few months ago, I had installed mysql on my ubuntu server, and I had success on accessing to mysql from remote Window-OS PC by MysqlWorkbench tool.
- But it's not working now. I have re-installed mysql, but something's wrong now.

Maybe...

- I think it's a simple connection problem.
- I want to check ssh connection or something like that.
- I hope you guys to tell me how to approach this problem.

I'm getting this error:

[image: Workbench configs for connecting to MySQL]

I have granted all privileges for root to access from any IPs.

[image]

Comment: If you can reach the server with the basic `mysql` command line client, then chances are you can reach it with `mysqlworkbench` as well, and with the same settings. You need server name, port, user name, password, and optionally database name.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) instead.

Comment: Make sure it is not apparmor blocking access. And "for root to access from any IPs." Why? Have a bit of common sense and create a specific user for this task. And a specific set of rules from a user. No dropping databases, functions, views or tables from workbench, no altering of tables from workbench, and o mass deleting from workbench.

Answer (score 4):

**If you have grant all privileges then you need to do this.**

To access remotely, for mysql server running on Ubuntu 16.04,
modify file `50-server.cnf`. (In earlier version it was `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.)

and comment out line `skip-external-locking` and `bind-address      = 127.0.0.1`.

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

#skip-external-locking

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
```

or you can also set bind-address only for your ip as `bind-address=youriip`

- `bind-address` tells MySQL what interfaces to listen on
- `skip-external-locking`: Do not listen for TCP/IP connections at
  all.This option is for systems where only local requests are allowed. To allow remote connection, comment out this line.

Comment: Thank you, daisy. I found the problem. My bind-address was '127.0.0.1'. After I comment out it, it works. Thank you~!

Comment: @user2730030 Then please vote up and accept it to mark it as solved.

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer, in Ubuntu server 18.04, my file path is : /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/msqld.cnf

Answer (score 0):

Log will show you that you need to create new user either 'username'@'your_desktop_hostname' or 'username'@'your_ISP_IP' on the server where actual mysql is running. Depending upon log entry, you need to add the user.